# What are memory primitives in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory

I'm reading *Docker in Action* and there is this sentence:

> Docker creates a unique IPC namespace for
>   each container by default. The Linux IPC namespace partitions share
>   memory primitives such as named shared memory blocks and semaphores,
>   as well as message queues.

Despite the examples, I can't figure out what is the concept behind **memory primitives**, would you please explain this term?

Answer (score 3):

[man namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) has a section on **IPC namespaces**.

> IPC namespaces isolate certain IPC resources, namely, System V IPC
>          objects (see [svipc(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/svipc.7.html)) and (since Linux 2.6.30) POSIX message queues
>          (see [mq_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html)).  The common characteristic of these IPC mechanisms is that IPC objects are identified by mechanisms other than filesystem pathnames.

`man svipc` says it has three types of objects; shared memory objects, message queues, and semaphore sets (a semaphore is a more general case of a [mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524/what-is-a-mutex)).  Instead of a filesystem path, each object has a numeric ID.

And POSIX message queues are identified by a name, similar to a filename.  (The Linux implementation uses virtual files accessed through `/dev/mqueue/`).

System V IPC should be considered obsolescent and difficult to use.

- System V shared memory objects can be replaced by POSIX SHM, see [man shm_overview](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html).
- System V semaphores can be replaced using [POSIX mutexes inside POSIX shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389353/do-pthread-mutexes-work-across-threads-if-in-shared-memory).
- System V message queues can be replaced by, you guessed it, POSIX message queues.

Notice that Linux IPC namespaces do *not* isolate POSIX SHM.  The Linux implementation accesses the objects through `/dev/shm/`, which is a `tmpfs` virtual filesystem.  If you want to isolate POSIX SHM, you use mount namespaces to change the filesystem that is mounted at `/dev/shm/`.

Answer (score 0):

Machine problem will exercise primitives for process control, signal management, pipes, and shared memory. The primitives in Unix are listed as follows:

```
 • Process Control
     fork:
     exec:
 • Signal Management
     sigset:
     kill:
 • Pipes and Files
     pipe:
     mknod:
     unlink:
     read/write:
 • Shared Memory
     shmget:
     shmat:
 • Semaphores (System V style)
     semget:
     semop:
 • ipcs: This command reports on the status of inter-process communication facilities. Allows you to monitor the correct use and operation of the interprocess communication primitives in your program.

• ipcrm: Remove a message queue, semaphore set, or shared memory ID. This comes in handy if your program does not clean up things correctly.

• kill: Terminate or signal a process. Comes in handy to clean up your processes.

• ps: Report on process status. This at least lists all your processes.
```

[Reference](http://faculty.cs.tamu.edu/bettati/Courses/410/2008C/Projects/mp3_unix.pdf)